# how to fill array from JSON for image slider in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have image slider in android studio, but images array from inside project.
I want to use images from JSON, how to the best solution..

this is my adapter

```
public class adapter_image_slider extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;

public adapter_image_slider(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sliderImagesId.length;
}

private int[] sliderImagesId = new int[]{
        R.drawable.imghome1, R.drawable.imghome2, R.drawable.imghome3,
};

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
    return v == ((ImageView) obj);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int i) {
    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    mImageView.setImageResource(sliderImagesId[i]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(mImageView, 0);
    return mImageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int i, Object obj) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) obj);
}

}
```

and this is my main activity :

```
public class activity_img_slider_json extends Fragment {

private static ViewPager mPager;
private static int currentPage = 0;
private static final Integer[] XMEN= {R.drawable.imghome1,R.drawable.imghome2,R.drawable.imghome3,};
private ArrayList<Integer> XMENArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_img_slider_json,null);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    for(int i=0;i<XMEN.length;i++)
        XMENArray.add(XMEN[i]);

    mPager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new adapter_img_slider_json(getActivity(), XMENArray));
    CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == XMEN.length) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
}

}
```

Thanks For Attention.

Comment: Instand of  ArrayList<Integer> XMENArray ; use  ArrayList<String> XMENArray ; and fill up that array list from your webservice response Json.

Comment: Inside your adapter class , Instand of using mImageView.setImageResource(sliderImagesId[i]); , load image from URL using picasso or glide what ever you like .for ex : Picasso.
  with(State.mainContext).
  load(sliderImagesId[i])).
  into(mImageView);

Comment: You can make a list of image url from your json and load images using picasso into youe image view

Comment: @Radhey can you give me an example, i'm very beginner in android. Thanks for Respons

Comment: if u want to display image from URLs try using image loading libraries like picasso